# xampp only showing my index file from my ht doc folder and nothing else

Tags: xampp

had to re install xampp due to any issue with another program that I no longer have install, reinstall it now it will only show the index page from the folder and nothing else and I check there is no issue with the ports

i have try to re install it a few times but the last time i try un stall it my laptop was saying it didn't have enough Memory to un stall it